# Show sys module parameter_names and values

Tags: filesystem

I'm looking for a quick way to check the parameters in `/sys/class/net/{NIC_Name}`. I can do `cat *` which gives me the values but I would like to display them in `parameter_name:value` pairs. Is there a built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to simply loop through the files and print each file's name, a colon, and its contents.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

cd /sys/class/net/"${1:?no interface name given}" || exit 1

for f in *; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        printf '%s:' "$f"
        cat -- "$f"
    fi
done
```

If you name that script `nic-params`, you can mark it as executable with `chmod +x nic-params` and run it as

```
./nic-params interface
```

where *`interface`* is the name of the interface (such as `wlp2s0`).

---

Any arguments after the first (`$1`) are ignored. If you forget to pass an argument, you get

```
./nic-params: 3: ./nic-params: 1: no interface name given
```

and the script exits. The special `:?` form of parameter expansion achieves that.

If you pass an argument that doesn't name a network interface, there is typically no directory by that name. Then you get

```
./nic-params: 3: cd: can't cd to /sys/class/net/argument
```

and the script exits reporting failure, due to `|| exit 1`.

Otherwise you get a list of properties (filename) and values (contents). It looks like this, but with many more lines:

```
addr_assign_type:0
addr_len:6
address:00:0c:29:be:ad:53
broadcast:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
carrier:1
carrier_changes:2
carrier_down_count:1
carrier_up_count:1
dev_id:0x0
```

Note that some lines will have `:` characters in them other than as a separator between a file's name and contents. If you find this confusing, you may want to use some delimiter other than `:` in the script.

Subdirectories, such as `queues`, `power`, and `statistics`, are not examined.

*Some of the lines will contain error messages.* That's because not all properties are meaningful for all kinds of interfaces. For example, `duplex` is only meaningful for Ethernet interfaces; otherwise, you get:

```
duplex:cat: duplex: Invalid argument
```

If you're processing the output, and sending standard output and standard error to multiple places, you may want to print an extra newline to standard output when `cat` fails (since the newline you do get is actually sent to standard error). To do this, change

```sh
        cat -- "$f"
```

to:

```sh
        cat -- "$f" || printf '\n'
```

But for just running the script in a terminal and inspecting the output, I think you'd prefer the script as shown above.